# How can I add a number of days to a timestamp in SQL so that it works for both postgreSQL and H2 database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, h2

I need something like

```
update public.myTable
set myRow = myOtherRow + interval '15' DAY
where myRow is null;
```

...but working :D Can anyone help, please? It has to work on both postgreSQL and H2. Thanks!

Both rows are of type timestamp and when I try to build the project with my migration (mvn clean install) I get:

```
Migration V3_8__my_migration.sql failed
-----------------------------------------------------
SQL State : 42000
Error Code : 42000
Message : Syntax error in SQL expression "UPDATE PUBLIC.MYTABLE
SET MYROW = MYOTHERROW + INTERVAL '15'[*] DAY
WHERE MYROW IS NULL "
Syntax error in SQL statement "UPDATE PUBLIC.MYTABLE
SET MYROW = MYOTHERROW + INTERVAL '15'[*] DAY
WHERE MYROW IS NULL "; SQL statement:
update public.myTable
set myRow = myOtherRow+ interval '15' DAY
where myRow is null [42000-193]
Location : db/migration/...
Line : 1
Statement : update public.myTable
set myRow = myOtherRow + interval '15' DAY
where myRow is null
```

Comment: That should work on both databases. What data type are the **columns** `myRow` and `myOtherRow`? What is the error you get?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for the answer! I have added the details in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

My issue seem to be solved by using H2 version 1.4.200. The current newest version gave me the error above.